# Gmail ignoring display:none

Tags: css, email, gmail, html-email, display

What I'm trying to do is have two tables that are either visible or not visible depending on what device you are viewing on. Here is my media query:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.hidedesktop {
   display:table !important; 
   overflow:visible !important; 
   line-height:100% !important; 
   visibility:visible !important;}

.hide { 
   display:none !important; 
   width:0px !important;
}
```

My first table works correctly, but my second table doesn't hide on desktop

```
<table class="hide">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> Show this on desktop. Hide on mobile.

      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table class="hidedesktop" style="overflow:hidden; display:none; line-height:0px; max-height:0px; visibility: hidden;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> Hide on desktop. Show on mobile </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Anyone have a fix for this? From what I can tell, this is only an issue in gmail, but I fear I'll have this issue with other email clients.

Comment: You have an extra bracket in this line width:0px !important;}

Comment: Thanks for the catch, that must have happened when pasting the code here.

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot rely on stylesheets in emails. Only use inline style. Check and recheck. Some CSS properties are simply ignored by certain mail clients. Specifically because they believe email is a place where you should be more "secure" than on a web page. Therefore the ability to load or run scripts or other resources, or to hide email contents or even to change the way links look, is impaired. You're better off sending a link to a webpage than sending responsive emails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after looking further into an email from J.Crew that I was trying to replicate for practice, I have found the solution.

```
.hide {display:none !important; width:0px !important;}

.showme {display:table !important;
    width:100% !important;
    overflow:visible !important;
    float:none !important;
    max-height:inherit !important;
    line-height:auto !important;
    margin-top:0px !important;
    visibility:inherit !important;}

.mobilenav {
    width:100% !important;
    margin: 0 auto !important;}
```

I found that wrapping my table in a parent div along with a few other CSS rules did the trick!

```
<table class="hide">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> Show this on desktop. Hide on mobile.</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div class="showme" style="display:none; overflow:hidden; float:left; width:0px; max-height:0px; line-height:0px; visibility:hidden;">
<table class="mobilenav showme" width="100%" style="display:none;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> Hide on desktop. Show on mobile </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

While it works on gmail desktop, I could not get the mobile table to display in the gmail app. But, only the top table displayed (as if I was viewing on a desktop), so it worked out perfectly for me.

This was also litmus tested!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, media queries don't work in Gmail or the Gmail app. You'll have to choose which one to show by default, and that will also be shown in Gmail and the Gmail app.

Comment: I saw a J.Crew email that had a navigation bar in the footer that would only display on mobile and they were able to hide it in gmail. I checked their source code and I didn't see anything special about it. It looks very similar to what I have but I can't replicate it.